# Sent post request and server is responding with the generated Id(Number)

Tags: html, angular4-httpclient

Getting the following error when I tried to subscribe that response. (how to handle response) (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable))
  student.component.ts //component file

```
respData:number; //declared respData as a number type

addNewStudent(){ //function calling from html page to send data to 
                   //service.ts
this.studentService.addNewStudentTest(this.newStudentForm.value).subscribe(
data=>{
this.respData=data;
console.log(this.respData);
},err => {
console.log("Error occured.")
});
}

student.service.ts

addNewStudentTest(student):Observable<Number>{
return this.httpC.post<Number>(url, student);
}
```

Comment: thanks, resolved the issue by changed response from XML to JSON. worked for me.